# How to add hindi support in xdime page for IBM WebSphere Portal 8 using MPA

Tags: utf-8, websphere, websphere-portal

I want my xdime page to be displayed in Hindi. However I am getting ???? in place of Hindi characters. I have taken care that my Hindi character properties file is in UTF-8 and has unicode characters. Also I've set Charset to UTF-8 in view.jsp. Hindi locale support has been added to portal and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default character set to UTF-8 of the XDIME markup for each local on the Supported Markups section on Administration page.